# Inline Code For a GitHub README Using MediaWiki

Tags: github, mediawiki, markup

I'm writing a `README.mediawiki` file for my project called [plainBlog](https://github.com/nathanpc/plainblog) on GitHub, but I want to add some inline code on it. What is the syntax for this? Also, what is the syntax for XML code (multiple lines)?

An example of inline code is located at [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#readme), where we have lines like this: `gem install wikicloth`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few:

```
 Start each line with a space.
 Text is '''preformatted''' and
 ''markups'' '''''can''''' be done
```

or:

```
<pre> Text is '''preformatted''' and
''markups'' '''''cannot''''' be done</pre>
```

For inline `<code>` spans there is no special syntax:

```
<code>Source code</code>
```

From http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting

Comment: `<code>` is not suited for ***inline*** code, since it's a block tag. One can use `<tt>` instead.

Comment: @Artefact2: [code](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1) is not a block tag.

Comment: @Artefact2: `<tt>` is [not an HTML5 element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-elements).  It does exist in HTML4 and below though, but is certainly not recommended for any new work.